# Symfony 2, autoload.php generated in wrong directory

Tags: symfony, composer-php, symfony-2.1

I'm using symfony 2 and trying to run `composer install --ignore-platform-reqs`

It worked before, but now on a fresh setup I'm getting an error `require_once(app/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

Full error below:

```sh
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in composer.json. You may be getting outdated dependencies. Run update to update them.
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
> Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap

Warning: require_once(app/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Users/macbook/www/myproject/source/vendor/sensio/distribution-bundle/Sensio/Bundle/DistributionBundle/Resources/bin/build_bootstrap.php on line 29

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'app/autoload.php' (include_path='.:') in /Users/macbook/www/myproject/source/vendor/sensio/distribution-bundle/Sensio/Bundle/DistributionBundle/Resources/bin/build_bootstrap.php on line 29
Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap handling the post-install-cmd event terminated with an exception


  [RuntimeException]                                     
  An error occurred when generating the bootstrap file.
```

The problem is that it worked before. So it looks like `app/autoload.php` was always in the correct place. Now I'm doing fresh install and it is not there.

I was able to find `autoload.php` in `vendors/autoload.php` but not sure why it located in the wrong place.

My composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.1.*",
        "doctrine/orm": ">=2.2.3,<2.4-dev",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.0.*",
        "twig/extensions": "1.0.*@dev",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "jms/security-extra-bundle": "1.2.*",
        "jms/di-extra-bundle": "1.1.*",
        "kriswallsmith/assetic": "1.1.*@dev",
        "doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle": "3.0.*",
        "snc/redis-bundle": "2.1.*@dev",
        "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "dev-master",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ],
        "update-parameters": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml",
            "env-map": {
                "mongodb_server": "MONGODB_SERVER"

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in composer.json".  Looks like someone messed around with composer.json and did not create a new lock file.  Might try deleting the lock file and update again.  Probably won't work.  app/autoload.php should have been checked in to your source code repository.  It's not going to be generated except for a new project.  Just copy it from a working app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After installation, composer runs a script from this file: [ScriptHandler.php](https://github.com/sensiolabs/SensioDistributionBundle/blob/2.1/Composer/ScriptHandler.php), which gets the path for config key `symfony-app-dir` and calls the next script from the file: [build_bootstrap.php](https://github.com/sensiolabs/SensioDistributionBundle/blob/2.1/Resources/bin/build_bootstrap.php)

If you do not have an `autoload.php` file, you probably need to copy it from the [autoload.php.dist](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.1/autoload.php.dist) file

Comment: true, is should've been there but it was removed by an accident.